# How to correct the order of execution tkinter code in a right way?

Tags: python, tkinter, execution

I have `func1()` which calls `func2()`, but the call of `func2()` starts after full completing of `func1()`. How to execute `func2()` right now, no after full completing of `func1()`?
My code:

```
def func1(self):
    self.path='1'
    self.func2()
    print self.path   #I want to get correct path, not '1'

def func2(self):
    self.openFileBut = Button(self, text="Open image", command=self.openFileBut)
    self.openFileBut.pack(side=LEFT, fill=None)

def openFileBut(self):
    ftypes = [('All files', '*')]
    dlg = tkFileDialog.Open(self, filetypes=ftypes)
    f = dlg.show()
    self.path = f
    if self.path != '':
        self.createCanv(self.path)
```

Comment: I got it.It will work if i press to my Button

Comment: Your code makes no sense; you're creating a button object that replaces the method you want pressing it to call. Also it's not clear why you'd expect just defining the button would make the user already have used it.

Comment: `__init__` and `default` differences. Create a button without any `command`, prepare your data/all_states before any binding, add command to button with all variants/arguments. Single function create your app(`if name main`) and "why do not use single function for all variants of a button ?"

Comment: And why you use `tkFileDialog.Open` ? Here's more pythonic method `askopenfile`. You can use it like this `file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(self, filetypes=ftypes); self.path = file.name if file is not None else ''`